# How to move div down when on small screen using Bootstrap?

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, inline-styles

I'm using a Jumbotron div from Bootstrap 3.9 to layout some content. There's some rows within it. While it looks great on the desktop, the Jumbotron's background image obscures the text in one of the internal rows. I need to move the text down when on small screens. I don't have access to the stylesheet, so everything has to be inline styled.

Desktop view: 
[image: Example of attempted project]

Mobile view: 
[image: Example of attempted project]

I've tried adding .col-sm-12 to the col-md-3 row below and for the col-md-9. It's ignored in Chrome.

```
<div>
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background-image:url(/uploads/div-background_01.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-color:#fff;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <br />
                <br />
                <h1 class="text-right" style="-webkit-text-stroke: 2px #ffdbe3;"><strong>HEADER TEXT</strong></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">

                Paragraph of text here.

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The image is added as a background image to the jumbotron div as that's the only way I could get the layout correct. I have zero chance of being able to get at the stylesheet, so I need to figure this out on my own.

Comment: Is the desktop view the way you want it to look? What if you made the background image not the background, and just a regular image, and then you can align it like another column in a row?

Comment: Yep, the "best view" is on desktop. I took your suggestion and just added the text on top of the image as one picture and added it in. It'll work. 

Thank you for responding.